# Is there a way to use modern Nvidia drivers for Intel-Nvidia hybrid notebooks?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, switchable-graphics

I'm reading that modern Nvidia driver installations for mobile cards don't support the Intel-Nvidia hybrid mode. For those who don't know about it, it's designed to save notebook battery charge by switching to Intel's slower and less energy demanding graphics system with a hotkey.

Several user-modified releases of video drivers exist of newer driver releases that are aimed to fully support all the features of this hybrid graphics system. But I'm not interested in all that. I'm only interested in Nvidia part of this hybrid system, since it's performance I'm after, not energy saving.

The thing is that the latest officially supported drivers are pretty old and I'd like to get the more recent version, and without the "unofficial support" by community that comes with another set of problems.

Is there a way to install newest Nvidia mobile graphics drivers ignoring the Intel part of the equation? Specifically, I'm looking for solutions for my Asus UL30VT with G210m Nvidia graphics, but I'm still interested in answers for all Nvidia mobile graphics.

Comment: If the laptop manufacturer will let you - not all do - you can install both NVidia & Intel's generic drivers, rather than the lappy-maker's version.

Comment: If your not interested in the hybrid feature, which is a worried about energy savings, not performance then simply installing Nvidia's current drivers and uninstalling Intel's drivers woudl accomplish your goals.

Comment: Nvidia driver installer says no compatible video card is found. This is why I'm asking.